# Incorrect datatype conversion when migrating from Mongo to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, mongodb, sqlalchemy

I have a Python script that fetches data from Mongo and dumps it into SQL Server.
I have a custom function that converts the fields that have 'date' or 'Date' as a substring into datetime datatype but it is converting it into VARCHAR.

```
    def to_date(df):
    date_columns = [column for column in df.columns if 'Date' in column or 'date' in column]
    for column in date_columns:
        if df[column].dtype == 'object':  # Check if the column is of type 'object' (string)
            df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df[column],errors='coerce',dayfirst= True)
    return df
```

this is my custom function that has to convert it into datetime datatype but it converts it into varchar

Comment: When you say SQL, are you actually referencing to SQL Server? (SQL is a data query standard implemented by many vendors).

Comment: yes i mean SQL Server

Comment: How are you protecting against the case when `to_datetime()` returns `NaT` for an invalid input?

Comment: _id, Data Type: object
DeleteMark, Data Type: int64
CreatedBy, Data Type: object
CreatedDate, Data Type: object
ModifiedBy, Data Type: object
ModifiedDate, Data Type: object
StoreCode, Data Type: object
StoreName, Data Type: object
Status, Data Type: object
Description, Data Type: object
Column Name: Acl, Data Type: object
Attributes, Data Type: object
StartDate, Data Type: datetime64[ns]
ReviewDate, Data Type: datetime64[ns]
EndDate, Data Type: datetime64[ns]
Column Name: StoreContacts, Data Type: object
StoreAddresses, Data Type: object

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i have no idea to be honest

Comment: Please [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reading [ask] and [mre] will likely increase chances of getting answers. Taking the [tour] is also quite informative.